# How do I access MySQL from CloudBees Jenkins?

Tags: mysql, jenkins, cloudbees

I cannot figure out how to access a MySQL database while running in Jenkins CloudBees. I have tried following the [Dev@Cloud MySQL](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/MySQL), but there are a lot of warnings in the console output and I have to deal with localhost access vs. sockets, which is pretty tricky to debug without a command line.

Is there a way to use the CloudBees MySQL hosting? When I try and use the cloudbees JDBC driver, I get ClassNotFound error messages.

**Update**: The answer below clarified that I cannot use the CloudBees driver, so I am now using the regular MySQL connector through the c3p0 connection pool. Based on comments below, I have limited the number of connections in the pool to 10.

The exact same configuration and Maven command line works when I run it from my development computer, connecting to the Cloudbees Mysql instance.

Unfortunately, I get this error when trying to connect:

```
Caused by: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:864)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:591)
    at com.assuredlabor.db.DatabaseMigrator.migrate(DatabaseMigrator.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 74 more
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the CloudBees JDBC driver. You should just be able to use the MySQL jdbc drivers and everything should Just Work.

Comment: I think he means the "special" jdbc URL format that works within RUN@cloud only. He needs to construct the MySQL URL with the db server host name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use CloudBees JDBC driver from outside the RUN@Cloud container, but you can use a standard MySQL JDBC driver with your RUN database using the host name and port that you can find on RUN@Cloud web console for your DB resource.

Comment: I thought about that. This may be my own ignorance, but don't we run the risk of AWS shutting down our server and moving it to another location? Wouldn't this cause a manual configuration headache?

Comment: I am trying this solution, but I keep getting this error: "Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User assured already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections". I don't think this is a code problem on my side, the tests run fine locally.

Comment: Your database is pinned to an IP address on CloudBees, so even if the server instance changes, the way you connect to it will be the same.

Active connections is a separate issues, and should probably be discussed on a different thread. But to answer, you are limited to 20 connections on the shared database configuration.  If you need more connections, contact sales@cloudbees.com to upgrade to a dedicated server configuration.

Comment: Thanks @swashbuck1r, its strange, my software shouldn't be making more than 20 connections, but I'll check it out. Maybe my connection pool starts up that many connections out of the box. Your right, its a topic for another thread.

Comment: I re-accepted this answer and added the other problem I was having, which is that my tests were leaking connections (kind of obvious in hind-sight)